# Dataframe group by a specific column, aggerage ratio of some other column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Data Frame with columns: `Year` and `Min Delay`. Sample rows as follows:

```
2014    0
2014    2
2014    0
2014    4
2015    4
2015    4
2015    2
2015    2
```

I want to group this dataframe by year and find the **delay ratio** per year (i.e. number of non-zero entries that year divided by total number of entries for that year). So if we consider the data frame above, what I am trying to get is:

```
2014  0.5
2015  1
```

(There are 2 delays in 2014, total 4, 4 delays in 2015 total 4. A delay is defined by Min Delay > 0)

This is what I tried:

```
def find_ratio(df):
    ratio = 1 - (len(df[df == 0]) / len(df))
    return ratio


print(df.groupby(["Year"])["Min Delay"].transform(find_ratio).unique())
```

which prints: `[0.5 1]`

How can I get a data frame instead of an array?

Comment: I think the problem is with the`.unique()` call - it returns a NumPy array - `ndarray` ([source](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.Series.unique.html))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I think `unique` is not good idea use here. Because if need assign output of function to years, it is impossible.

Also `transform` is good idea if need new column to DataFrame, not aggregated DataFrame.

---

I think need [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html), also function should be simplify by mean of boolean mask:

```
def find_ratio(df):
    ratio = (df != 0).mean()
    return ratio

print(df.groupby(["Year"])["Min Delay"].apply(find_ratio).reset_index(name='ratio'))

   Year  ratio
0  2014    0.5
1  2015    1.0
```

Solution with lambda function:

```
print (df.groupby(["Year"])["Min Delay"]
         .apply(lambda x: (x != 0).mean())
         .reset_index(name='ratio'))

   Year  ratio
0  2014    0.5
1  2015    1.0
```

Solution with [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) return new column:

```
df['ratio'] = df.groupby(["Year"])["Min Delay"].transform(find_ratio)
print (df)
   Year  Min Delay  ratio
0  2014          0    0.5
1  2014          2    0.5
2  2014          0    0.5
3  2014          4    0.5
4  2015          4    0.0
5  2015          4    0.0
6  2015          2    0.0
7  2015          2    0.0
```

Comment: Downvoter, if there's something wrong with my answer, please let me know, so I can correct it. Thanks.